# Bind with Butterknife to dynamically added view in android

Tags: android, butterknife

How Can I bind the views present inside the Layout which is dynamically added to the parent view with ButterKnife.

I have a LinearLayout say **container**. And I have a custom layout which contains two buttons say this layout as **childview**
In activity I added the **childview** successfully to the parent LinearLayout **container**.

This is how I did to inflate the custom view and added to the LinearLayout

```
bubbleView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child, null);
systemChatLayoutContainer.addView(bubbleView);
```

Now I want to bind the Button views present inside the **child** layout
and add perform some action when the buttons present inside the **child** layout.

This is child.xml which is dynamically added to the parent container on Button click.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btnCreateAccount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_selector_green"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/_13sdp"
        android:text="Create an account"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btnJstCheckingRate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_selector_blue"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/_13sdp"
        android:text="I'm just checking rates"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btnIhaveAccount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_btn_selector"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:text="I've got an account"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can bind views with ButterKnife present inside the child layout using `ViewHolder`, so add the inner class `BubbleViewHolder`

```
class BubbleViewHolder {
    BubbleViewHolder(View view) {
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.button_id)
    void onMyButtonClicked(Button myButton) {
        // Do your stuff here
    }
}
```

And construct the `BubbleViewHolder` after inflating it

```
View bubbleView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child, null);
new BubbleViewHolder(bubbleView);
systemChatLayoutContainer.addView(bubbleView);
```

Comment: isn't there way to implement @OnClick  of ButterKnife to perferom action ?

Comment: If you want to, you can inside this viewholder. If this solution works can you please upvote the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: In my case i had to change inner class from `private` to `protected` to avoid error `@BindView fields may not be contained in private classes`