# How to bind view inflated in activity after bind all the views with ButterKnife

Tags: java, android, butterknife

I need to bind views inflated after binding the activity views with butter knife   without using    `ButterKnife.findById(this,view);`    because its deprecated.

I need this because if i use the android    `findViewBy()` it will not listen to the    `@onClick()` notation for the ButterKnife.

Note : I am using ButterKnife 8.8.1

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can bind the view when declaring the variables. It should bind your view instances.

```
@BindView(R.id.button) Button mButton;

@OnClick(R.id.button)
public void onButtonClicked(View view) {
    // TODO 
}
```

Comment: i already know that , the problem if the view has not inflated yet,and the i need to bind it after i inflated it

Comment: Adding a view holder like this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37744720/bind-with-butterknife-to-dynamically-added-view-in-android

Comment: Thank you , that's helped a lot .

Comment: Glad it help! Good luck :)